# How to merge two dataframes spark java/scala based on a column?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a two dataframes DF1 and DF2 with **id** as the unique column,
DF2 may contain a new records and updated values for existing records of DF1, when we merge the two dataframes result should include the new record and a old records with updated values remain should come as it is.

Input example:

```
id   name
10   abc
20   tuv
30   xyz
```

and

```
id   name
10   abc
20   pqr
40   lmn
```

When I merge these two dataframes, I want the result as:

```
id   name
10   abc
20   pqr
30   xyz
40   lmn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an outer `join` followed by a `coalesce`. In Scala:

```
val df1 = Seq((10, "abc"), (20, "tuv"), (30, "xyz")).toDF("id", "name") 
val df2 = Seq((10, "abc"), (20, "pqr"), (40, "lmn")).toDF("id", "name")

df1.select($"id", $"name".as("old_name"))
  .join(df2, Seq("id"), "outer")
  .withColumn("name", coalesce($"name", $"old_name"))
  .drop("old_name")
```

`coalesce` will give the value of the first non-null value, which in this case returns:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
| 20| pqr|
| 40| lmn|
| 10| abc|
| 30| xyz|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "leftanti").union(df2).show

| id|name|
+---+----+
| 30| xyz|
| 10| abc|
| 20| pqr|
| 40| lmn|
+---+----+
```

Comment: It is not an answer, it is a comment to @Shaido answer. You've updated his last statement only.

Comment: `df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "leftanti").union(df2)` is my answer.  The user already got two dataframes df1 and df2 defined in the question. I don't have to redefine them. @Shaido's last statement(the table) is the output of his answer. My table is the output of my answer, if you take a further look, the tables are not exactly the same. Both are right